# How to display different images with jQuery when an option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

How to display different images when an option is selected?

Here is my markup:

```
<select name="brand-range">
    <option value="Brand1">BFS</option>
    <option value="Brand2">FS</option>
    <option value="Brand3">PS</option>
</select>

<div class="option-image" id="thumbs">
    <div id="bfs"><img src="images/hotel0.jpg"/></div>
    <div id="fs"><img src="images/hotel1.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="ps"><img src="images/hotel2.jpg" /></div>                                                             
</div>
```

I'm looking for a jQuery solution. 
Any suggestions highly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the JS code you've written yourself to the question.

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now your question is equivalent to: "Give me the codz plz, in jQuery."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML code, i've written script, since option text and image div id value is same i've written script based on that. Refer and the code do changes accordingly.

Here on change of dropdown, i'm getting options values and since images parent div's value are id are same i'm getting that element and changing its css.
Note: you have to change your HTML structure so that you can make changes through jquery accordingly.

```
$("#brandrange").bind("change", function() {
  var image_element = ($("option:selected").text()).toLowerCase();
  $("#thumbs").find("div").css("display", "none");
  $("#thumbs").find("#" + image_element).css("display", "block");
});
```

Here is JSfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/90sybgyw/1/